# How to get feature in list?

Tags: features

I created a feature and I can download it directly.

But how do I get it in the list (/admin/structure/features) in order to recreate it?

Comment: ensure you check the vertical tabs on the left to ensure you are seeing it, it should show up automatically

Comment: I'm afraid to install it in the same dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a feature it will make that feature as a module. So, after it got downloaded you need to put those files in to `sites/all/modules/` and then enable it from `admin/modules`. So you can see that `(/admin/structure/features)` .

Comment: I understand but then this should be done in the same development environment or in the staging environment?